# Bitmap.GetPixel() returns bad value

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap

I'm having some trouble reading back pixel values from a Bitmap that I'm generating.  I first generate a bitmap named maskBitmap in my class  using this code:

```
    void generateMaskBitmap()
    {
        if (inputBitmap != null)
        {
            Bitmap tempBitmap = new Bitmap(inputBitmap.Width, inputBitmap.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(tempBitmap))
            {
                Brush brush = Brushes.Black;
                for (int y = 0; y < tempBitmap.Height; y += circleSpacing)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < tempBitmap.Width; x += circleSpacing)
                    {
                        g.FillEllipse(brush, x, y, circleDiameter, circleDiameter);
                    }
                }
                g.Flush();
            }

            maskBitmap = (Bitmap)tempBitmap.Clone();
        }
    }
```

I then try to apply the mask to my original image using the following code:

```
    void generateOutputBitmap()
    {
        if (inputBitmap != null && maskBitmap != null)
        {
            Bitmap tempBitmap = new Bitmap(inputBitmap.Width, inputBitmap.Height);
            for (int y = 0; y < tempBitmap.Height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < tempBitmap.Width; x++)
                {
                    Color tempColor = maskBitmap.GetPixel(x, y);

                    if (tempColor == Color.Black)
                    {
                        tempBitmap.SetPixel(x, y, inputBitmap.GetPixel(x, y));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tempBitmap.SetPixel(x, y, Color.White);
                    }
                }
            }
            outputBitmap = tempBitmap;
        }
    }
```

The mask bitmap is successfully generated and visible in a picture box, however the color values for every pixel when testing "`tempColor`" show empty (A = 0, R = 0, G = 0, B = 0).  I am aware of the performance problems with getpixel/setpixel, but this is not an issue for this project.  I'm also aware that `"tempColor == Color.Black"` is not a valid test, but that is just a place holder for my comparison code.

Comment: When you say, "The mask bitmap is successfully generated and visible", clearly you see a pattern of black dots.  But what's the background color?  Is it just the default picture box color?  It seems to me that you're not setting the background of your mask, so those values are uninitialized, and reporting 0,0,0.  Either filling your image with another color first, or just changing your mask color could avoid this.

Comment: If this is the problem, the difference between what you draw and what you don't is that what you draw should have an alpha of 100% while what you haven't initialized should have an alpha of 0%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unable to reproduce your problem. I copy-and-pasted your code and made some modifications to make it work for me. I am able to confirm that `tempColor` is sometimes #FF000000.

I suspect you mixed up your bitmap references somewhere. Are you *really* sure you are *never* getting any value other than #00000000? Do your `circleDiameter` and `circleSpacing` have sensible values? And most importantly: are you absolutely sure that you are reading from the correct bitmap?

Here's my version of your code, which I know works:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var bitmap = GenerateMaskBitmap(100, 100);
            TestMaskBitmap(bitmap);
        }

        const int CircleDiameter = 10;
        const int CircleSpacing = 10;

        static Bitmap GenerateMaskBitmap(int width, int height)
        {
            Bitmap maskBitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(maskBitmap))
            {
                Brush brush = Brushes.Black;
                for (int y = 0; y < maskBitmap.Height; y += CircleSpacing)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < maskBitmap.Width; x += CircleSpacing)
                    {
                        g.FillEllipse(brush, x, y, CircleDiameter, CircleDiameter);
                    }
                }
                g.Flush();
            }

            return maskBitmap;
        }

        static void TestMaskBitmap(Bitmap maskBitmap)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < maskBitmap.Height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < maskBitmap.Width; x++)
                {
                    Color tempColor = maskBitmap.GetPixel(x, y);

                    if (tempColor.ToArgb() != 0)
                        throw new Exception("It works!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```